# C: Function isn't updating global array (using strcpy / malloc)

Tags: c, arrays, windows, function, malloc

Trying to get the files names from a directory in Windows. Doing this by an function called list_files. The function is not doing anything for some reason (or it looks like it), cause whenever I print the array, it is empty.

I have tested this code before and it was working fine. I kept coding (this is a longer code originally) I noticed that it returned 0 (nothing) whenever I had to use the array later on

```
void list_files();

char *filesList[0][254];
int i = 0, n = 0, l = 254;
char directory[] = {"C:/Users/test/Downloads/test/"};

int main()
{
    list_files();
}

void list_files()
{
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir(directory);
    //Determine the number of files
    while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") != 0)
            n++; // determine, count array size based on files
    }
    rewinddir(d);
    //Put file names into the array
    while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") != 0)
        {
            filesList[i][l] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 100); // allocate memory
            strcpy(filesList[i][l], dir->d_name); // put file names in to array
            i++; // do +1 to read each single array line
        }
    }
    rewinddir(d);
    printf("%s",n);
    for(i;i<n;i++){
        printf("%s/n", filesList[i][l]);
    }
}
```

What I expect to see (or get) is an array filled in with filenames within a directory. in my case, the directory contains 3 files. The program isn't made for big files with x00 files. So when I print the array:

Hello.txt, bye.txt, bye.exe

Comment: Could you describe, in words, what you expect `char *filesList[0][254]` to give you?

Comment: At that moment, nothing. Later on, that changes. Considered reading the code further down..? @brhans also.. I get error when debugging the code whenever I fill in nothing, since the array size will be defined with the function.

Comment: @deoncagadoes I did debug it, didn't see anything weird.

Comment: @deoncagadoes `i` is used for the loops, `l` is used for length, that's the same all the time which is: 254.

Comment: Output from prints please.

Comment: @user3121023 tried it, not working..

Comment: Definitely needed, though one would have to add a check to make sure `i` doesn't exceed `253`.

Comment: Why are you using `100` instead of the correct amount?!?!?

Comment: Check the return value of `opendir`

Comment: We don't have to read the code "further down"...`char *filesList[0][254]` cannot possibly be meaningful. I'm surprised the compiler didn't complain (or maybe it did and you have warnings off?) You are declaring a global array of 0 things. There is no memory there to put things, and no way to allocate additional memory for other things. `fileList[x]...` will just write to random memory.

Comment: I;m not asking what's in it. I'm asking you what you think that statement declares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `char *fileList[254]` to declare an array of 254 pointers.
use loops `for(n = 0; n < i;n++){`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>

void list_files();

char *filesList[254];
int i = 0, n = 0, l = 254;
char directory[] = {"./"};

int main()
{
    list_files();
}

void list_files()
{
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir(directory);
    //Put file names into the array
    while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
        if ( ( i < 254) && ! ( strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") == 0))
        {
            filesList[i] = malloc( strlen ( dir->d_name) + 1); // allocate memory
            strcpy(filesList[i], dir->d_name); // put file names in to array
            i++; // do +1 to read each single array line
        }
    }
    for(n = 0; n < i;n++){
        printf("%s\n", filesList[n]);
    }
    for(n = 0; n < i;n++){
        free ( filesList[n]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! you're the best

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other problems noted, you never reset `i` in this code:

```
while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
    if (strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") != 0)
    {
        filesList[i][l] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 100); // allocate memory
        strcpy(filesList[i][l], dir->d_name); // put file names in to array
        i++; // do +1 to read each single array line
    }
}
rewinddir(d);
printf("%s",n);
for(i;i<n;i++){  
    printf("%s/n", filesList[i][l]);
}
```

When you reach

```
for(i;i<n;i++){
```

`i` is likely equal to `n`.  I say "likely" because your code doesn't account for the possibility that the number of entries in the directory can change between your two `readdir()` loops.

A quick fix for this is to simply set `i` to zero at the start of the `for` loop:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
```